# jquery adding a mail link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to finish up a contact section of a personal page where I have the URL for each of my social media / contact pages as text in the div. When users click on it, it goes to the stated link. But naturally for my email address, I want them to go their mail app. Thus I wrote this jquery:

```
$(".contact-info").click(function() {
    var link = $(this).text();
    if (link == "foo@bar.com") {
        link = "mailto:" + link;
    }
    window.location.href = link;
});
```

Along with this html and css if it helps:

```
<div class="contact-info">
    <div class="contact-img">
       <img src="assets/img/icon_at.png">
       <div class="contact-link">foo@bar.com</div>
    </div>
</div>

.contact-info {
    width: 40%;
    height: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 40px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

It works fine for the direct links, but the mail case always gives me a 404 Error. Would someone be able to tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

UPDATE: "contact-info" is the class I apply to each of my divs representing a mode of contact i.e. Facebook, LinkedIn, and email.

Comment: What is `.contact-info`? Why are you not just using links to start? Seems like you are recreating the wheel.

Comment: Works for me here: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/jbh2ovg3/

Comment: Above comment is also working for me.

Comment: It seems to be going to http://www.myDomain/foo@bar.com which I'm guessing why it is giving me a 404, rather than my mail client on my site.

Comment: Post the example html that fails...

Comment: cant u just use an anchor tag ?
`<a class="contact-link" href="mailto:foo@bar.com">foo@bar.com</a>`

Answer (score 1):

Hope this help

```
$(".contact-info").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this).text();
    if (link == "foo@bar.com") {
        link = "mailto:" + link;
    }
    window.location.href = link;
});
```

Comment: what default are you preventing on text in a div?

Comment: Hmm, sorry I forgot about 'text in the div'.

Comment: Use `===`. String to string comparison. No type coercion needed

Answer (score 1):

could always use match, just in case you have support/info/help/etc...

```
$(".contact-info").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this).text();
    window.location.href = (link.match('@')) ? "mailto:" + link : link;
});
```